# Links in the activity stream to tag wiki edits are broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-wiki, recent-activity, activity-summary

I edited some tag wikis, the edits have been approved and show up in my [activity stream](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/665/hendrik-brummermann?tab=activity),

But the links are 404. Instead of https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7242/webid-wiki-description the link should point to https://security.stackexchange.com/tags/webid/info

Comment: Nice catch. +1.

Comment: The link could be to `/q/7242`, which works, unlike `/questions/7242`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was fixed a while back... just tested it